# A question on a proof that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $20$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

My question regards the reasoning that was given in the answer to the question "Why does $A_5$ not have any subgroup of order $20$".  The particular question can be found here:

[Why $A_{5}$ has no subgroup of order 20?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169437/why-a-5-has-no-subgroup-of-order-20)

It seems that the answer can be found by assuming that $H$ is such a subgroup, and realizing that $A_5$ acts on the set of left cosets of $H$, therefore implying that $A_5$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_3$.  An answer to this question states that the above is true because $A_5$ is a simple group.

My question is what does the group $A_5$ being a simple group have to do with $A_5$ being isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_3$?  How does $A_5$ acting on the set of left cosets of $H$ imply this isomorphism?

Also, an a somewhat unrelated note we don't assume that the subgroup of order 20 is a normal subgroup, so we can't construct the quotient group $A_5/H$ which would have 3 elements, but how do we know then that the set of left cosets of $H$ will have precisely 3 elements?

Comment: The action of $A_5$ on the set of cosets gives a map $A_5\to S_3$.  The kernel of that map would be a normal subgroup of $A_5$, hence it must be all of $A_5$ (this is where we use the simplicity of $A_5$).  But that would mean that $A_5$ acts trivially on that set, which is clearly false.

Comment: How do we know that the kernel of the map you described above wouldn't be the trivial subgroup of $A_5$?  Namely the subgroup $\{1\}$ where 1 is the identity map.  And also, why is it that $A_5$ cannot act trivially on that set?

Comment: Because a group of order $60$ can not inject into a group of order $6$.

Comment: I'll let you think a bit about why $A_5$ can not act trivially on the cosets.  Just think about the nature of the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, let $G$ be a nontrivial finite group and $X_G$ the set of all the proper subgroups of $G$: $$X_G:=\{H\subseteq G\mid H\le G \wedge H\ne G\}.$$ If $G$ is *simple*, then:

$$[G:H]!\ge|G|, \space\forall H\in X_G \tag 1$$

In fact, for $H\in X_G$, the group $G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, and this action has trivial kernel$^\dagger$. So, $G$ embeds into $S_{[G:H]}$, whence $(1)$.

The constraint $(1)$ means that finite simple groups can't have "relatively big" subgroups. As for your case, from $(1)$ follows that $A_5$ can't have subgroups of order $15$, $20$ and $30$ (this latter is ruled out by the very simplicity of $A_5$, though), because $[60:k]!<60$ for $k=15, 20, 30$.

---

$^\dagger$For $H\in X_G$, we get: $K:=\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}\lneq G$, and thence $K=\{1\}$ for the simplicity of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $H$ is such a subgroup. The action of $A_5$ to the left cosets $A_5/H$ induces a homomorphism $\rho: A_5 \to S_3$ with $\boxed{\ker \rho \subseteq H}$. From that we deduce that $\ker \rho = \{1\}$ (due to $A_5$ being simple) and then $5!$ would divide $6$, a contradiction.

Comment: To complete the answer, you should briefly explain why $\rho$ can't be trivial, which is needed to demonstrate that $\ker \rho \neq A_5$.

Comment: @RobertShore Isn't that obvious? $\ker \rho$ is a subgroup of a proper subgroup of $A_5$.